# Ubuntu 16.04 says OS updates are available, then offers no way to update

Tags: 16.04, desktop-environments

Am I missing something here? I saw a popup notification saying OS updates were available. But in the gear icon, there's nothing to update. There's no other indication of how/where to update. Sure, I could just run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade` in a shell, but that's not the point. This seems to be a pretty huge oversight in the desktop UI design.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Ubuntu 16.04 or at least along that line, when you click on the Software updater and run it are there any update found for you to install?

Comment: Yes, there are. But there are two major failings from a UX standpoint: the popup has no way for the user to click it open the software updater or any other indication of what to do next, and the software updater is neither in the gear menu nor in the dock by default.

Comment: I see what you're saying when you see the updater notice in the top right hand corner of your desktop there is no way to click on it to get the updates corrects?

Comment: I believe this is one of the changes. In 14.04 one would have a dialog open and ask if you want to install updates. I suppose now users have to explicitly open Software Updater from Unity Dash.

Comment: I never really paid to much attention to the updater notice I just assumed it was in place to let me know when updates are available. When ever I see it I know my system has update to install